# Non-linear regression, new try at exponential family problem.

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, soft-question, nonlinear-optimization, regression

So I am trying to find some kind of an "easiest to understand problem" which is not very easy to solve with anything less than a quite sophisticated optimization framework. I will still of course welcome other solutions as well.

The idea is to find some way to do regression on:

$$f(x) = c_0+\exp[c_3x^2+c_2x+c_1], \\c_0,c_1,c_2,c_3\in \mathbb C, \\x\in \mathbb R$$

estimating $c_0,c_1,c_2,c_3$ parameters from linearly spaced data $x_k = kx$ and we know $(x_k,f(x_k)+e_k)$ potentially with some noise e.

---

Some famous (and useful) special cases of $f$ we want to be able to find:

$c_3=0,c_2\in \mathbb R$ gives exponential model offset by $c_0$, for example how money changes over time at constant interest if $\log c_1$ is in bank and $c_0$ is saved in piggy bank.

$c_3=0,c_2=\lambda i+b$ gives sinusoid of constant frequency and $b$ decides if it spirals.

$c_3=\lambda i,c_2=0$ gives a complex quadrature chirp of constant acceleration $\lambda$, like in a previous question which had (too) easy solution.

Comment: Do you know about linearisation?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe: I have tried many kinds of linearization techniques. Do you have a specific way in mind? =)

Comment: That $c_0$ is very distracting ...

Comment: @MichaelHoppe yes it would be a bit too easy if we could just do a log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f(x) = c_0+\exp\left(c_3x^2+c_2x+c_1\right) $$

A straightforward  method (no initial guess, no iteration) is shown below.

In order to comply with the symbols used in the sheet below,  one have to change the notations :
$$\begin{cases}
f(x)=y(x)\\
a=c_0 \\
b=e^{c_1} \quad\to\quad c_1=\ln(b)\\
p=c_3 \\
q=c_2
\end{cases}$$
$$y(x)=a+b\,e^{p\,x^2+q\,x}$$ 
This is a copy from a French paper.

[image]

[image]

COMMENT :

The method is based on the fitting of an integral equation. In the present case, the integral equation is :
$$y=2p\int xy\,dx+q\int y\,dx-apx^2-aqx+c$$
which comes from the integration of the function $y(x)=a+b\,e^{p\,x^2+q\,x}$.

For more explanation on the theory, see the paper : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales

The numerical integrations (calculus of $S_k$ and $T_k$) introduces some additional deviations if the number of points is too small.

The result is not exactly the least mean square deviation with respect to $y(x)$ but is a least mean square deviation with respect to the integral equation.

If the result is not sufficiently accurate, on cannot avoid to use a non-linear method of regression which requires some initial guess of the parameters. The above method gives approximates of the parameters which can be used as very good "guess".

Comment: Wow this is an ambitious way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

**Warning: This is a hacky solution :D.**

We have the model equation

$$y = \alpha+\exp[ax^2+bx+c], \\\alpha,a,b,c\in \mathbb C, \\x\in \mathbb R.$$

In the first step, we create a grid (structured or better random) of possible values for $\alpha$ and from this point assume that $\alpha^{[k]}$ is fixed, in which $k$ is the index of the $k^{\text{th}}$ possible value for $\alpha$ that we selected. Then we introduce a new dependent variable of $\exp(z^{[k]})=y-\alpha^{[k]}$. This will allow us to obtain the simplified regression equation

$$z^{[k]}=a^{[k]}x^2+b^{[k]}x+c^{[k]}.$$

This problem can be solved by a simple least squares regression. Then out of all the $k$ possible values for $\alpha^{[k]}$ we choose the one with the smallest test error. After having obtained this solution you can further refine your grid for $\alpha$ to obtain a better solution. In this method, I treated $\alpha$ as a hyperparameter instead of using it as a coefficient.

Note, that by this method we do not have any guarantees that the solution does globally minimize the sum of squared errors (if we use the squared error as our loss function). As the values for $y$ can be complex, we would need to use the sum of the squared magnitude of the error as our loss function.

Comment: If I may suggest, we need to be very careful since what is measured is $y$ and not $z$. That is to say that after doing what you propose (I totally agree with the approach) we have the parameters $(a^{[k]},b^{[k]},c^{[k]})$ and with those we need to compute the corresponding $y$ and the $SSQ$ for the $y$. You can prove that the minimum is unique. I made the work for the data set used by JJacquelin in his answer.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you for your comment. Could you explain a little bit further where the error lies in my reasoning?

Comment: The reasoning is OK. For a given $\alpha$, you get the coefficients by linear regression but, since what is measured is $y$ and not any of its possible transforms (such as $z$ in your case), you need to minimize the $SSQ$ based on the recomputed $y$'s from the $z$'s and not worry at all about the $SSQ$ of the linear regression. Is this clear ? Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I get your point. Thank you for responding.